# A relation in group theory

Tags: group-theory

Ler $G $ be a group and  $X $ a non empty subset of $G $ such that for all $g\in G $ we have $XgX=Xg$
. How can we show that $Xg=gX $, for all $g\in G $?

Comment: The group is not assumed to be *finite*, right?

Comment: No, $G $  is an arbitrary group.

Comment: Observations: We have $Xg\cdot Xh = XgX\cdot h =Xgh$. so $Q:=\{\,Xg\mid g\in G\,\}$ is a group with $X$ as neutral element and $Xg^{-1}$ as inverse of $Xg$, and $g\mapsto Xg$ is a group epimorphism $\phi\colon G\to Q$.
In particular, $XX=X$ and so $x\in X$ implies $x^n\in X$.